# Uncaught Error: Unexpected line: 'n 0 0 1' in THREE.OBJLoader.parse at line 541

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to read an `obj` file using `OBJLoader` in `three.js`. The code which I've written works well with other `obj` files but with this one I'm getting an error. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Error:
[image]

Link for `obj` file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EdYlsPD5hMvlKofGyaLmkx3isJR9tU1e

Comment: The loader does not support parsing the `n` syntax. What does it stand for? I have not found any information about it in the following unofficial documentation: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/

Comment: I don't know what n syntax means.

Comment: You might want to use `OBJLoader2` as a fallback. It does not parse the statement correctly, too. But at least it does not abort and produces a renderable result.